# How can I get the memory consumption peak of my program?

Tags: linux, memory, process

I have a small program, much like `grep` or `cat` that allocates memory when it is running. I would like to know how much memory is allocated at maximum throughout its run. How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `/usr/bin/time` for that purpose. Example:

```
/usr/bin/time -f '%M kB' command args...
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually if it's memory related I'll check if valgrind has it first:

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html

doing something like:

```
valgrind --tool=massif <program-name>
ms_print massif.<date>
```

Towards the top of the of the ms_print output should be a graph that will give you the info you desire.